# vba Access - Call a function from another function and close de first of them

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm writing an application in Access 2010. I need to open sub_b from sub_a. Usually I put "sub_b" inside of sub_a, but this time I need to close sub_a and I don't know if that's possible.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by closing? Do you want to stop execution of sub_a after sub_b has a certain state/result?

Comment: No, I want  to execute "sub_b", stop "sub_a"  and continue running "sub_b".

Answer (score 0):

In sub_a, after the call of sub_b insert this line:

```
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say your code is this :

sub sub_a()

'code before sub_b is called

if something then
    call sub_b
endif

'code after sub_b is called

end sub

if you want your code to execute the code before sub_b is called and the code in sub_b, then you have to write 
Exit
at the end of sub_b

Comment: Ok, but I think when you write "call sub_b", "sub_a" remains waiting for the end of "sub_b" and then control comes back to "sub_a". Thanks a lot, but I believe there is no way to do that. Looks like a job for threads, and access can't handle...